# android align text in textview through java

Tags: android, textview, alignment

I have a textview in which I append a few lines through java as follows.

```
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);
myTextView.append("this is line one of the textview");
myTextView.append("this is line two");
myTextView.append("this is line three of the textview");
```

I want to center align only the second line. I've tried different html tags but none work.
Could someone please tell me how it is done in android.

Answer (score 8):

```
myTextView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
```

Comment: that will align the entire text in the center. I want to align only the second line.

Answer (score 2):

HTML tags works, you just need to put them correctly.

```
myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<center>"+"this is line two"+"</center>"));
```

I don't know if it works with `append()` too. Try and let me know if it works.

Comment: if it is the only line then it works, but if I put anything before or after it, then it doesn't.